# Как по кредам зайти на Azure?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, ip, visual-studio-code, azure

Как зайти под представленной учетной записью на базу Database in Azure?  Мой IP внесли, но я на руководствах MSDN не нашел как зарегистрироваться.

Comment: Так же, как на обычный sql server - вписываете креды в диалоге подключения ssms - и все. Если в мастер не пустит - задайте имя базы там же, в advanced настройках